# Preventing hotlinking in IIS7 and ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What is the most straightforward way to prevent hotlinking in ASP.NET MVC 3 and IIS7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, ASP.Net MVC 3 is still ASP.Net underneath. Which means you can use standard methods. For example the [LeechGuard](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1288) Module provided by Microsoft.

Comment: BTW, that's not by Microsoft.

Comment: @SLaks I stand corrected. Just assumed because of the copyright notice.

Comment: @Yuriy: isn't it only a matter of providing the right REFERRER and even this tool is useless?